# How do i prove that $ Z_n $ is a subring of $ Z_m $ using the subring test?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Let $n, m \in Z^+ \setminus {1} $. Assume $ n|m $. How do i prove that $ Z_n $ is a subring of $ Z_m $ using the subring test? Do i just have to follow the 3 conditions for the subring test?  or there is something else i need to realize considering the assumption $ n|m $? i'm confused because it is not explicitly stated that $ Z_n \subseteq Z_m$. pls help me. thanks!

Comment: In this case, part of the question is figuring out in what way $Z_n$ is a subring of $Z_m$ -- that is, instead of a literal inclusion $Z_n \subseteq Z_m$ you have to give an injective function $Z_n \to Z_m$ and how that this is a ring homomorphism. (Note: this is not a ring homomorphism in the most common sense of the word, as it will not send 1 to 1.)

Comment: so how do i do that?